# How makeSetValue, makeGetValue and maybeExport are working in emscripten?

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I see `makeSetValue`, `makeGetValue` and `maybeExport` in many scripts, for example in [preamble.js](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/src/preamble.js)

But I don't know how to use them, or how they really work, because this functions aren't mentioned in the documentation.

Example code:

```
function writeArrayToMemory(array, buffer) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    {{{ makeSetValue('buffer++', 0, 'array[i]', 'i8') }}};
  }
}

{{{ maybeExport('writeArrayToMemory') }}}
```

Answer (score 2):

`{{{ ... }}}` is macro, it is extracted at compile time.
Use `--js-library` option like `emcc --js-library lib_foo.js main.c ...`.

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/src/parseTools.js

lib_foo.js:

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  writeArrayToMemory: function(array, buffer) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      {{{ makeSetValue('buffer++', 0, 'array[i]', 'i8') }}};
  }
  }
});
```